# Selenium configuration for single node

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm assuming that this is the main Selenium plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

It seems to be set up to have 'hub' and 'node' instances of selenium-server running. 
I see that it starts up and manages the hub selenium-server which is great, as I don't want the overhead of managing and starting/stopping individual nodes.
Is it possible to run tests directly on the hub?

At the moment I get the following error in the test when trying to do that:

`PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{browserName=phantomjs}]`

I get the same error when I change to firefox.

(I've phantomjs installed fine on the server, and it's able to execute fine when selenium-server is run directly as a standalone server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the current maintainer of the Jenkins selenium plugin. You cannot use the selenium hub as a node no. When you start the selenium-server manually as hub and node at the same time, you're kinda breaking the hub aspect of it (behaves unexpected sometimes), and it's not really intended to be used in this way. However you really only need to start your created node profile once, from then on the plugin will auto-start/stop the grid node for you when Jenkins starts/stops.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what a 'created node profile' is, does that mean the plugin will also start a separate node? I can't see any documentation on that. (I've since been manually starting another node on the same server).
Under `Registered Remote Controls` I have `No RCs have checked in yet. Have you started some slaves?`

Comment: On the left hand side you should have a link to configurations. Click on that. Then add a new configuration with the browsers you want to add (or if you can't find it, append this after your jenkins url `/selenium/add`). Give your configuration a name to identify it, and choose a matcher strategy. If you have only one Jenkins slave, just choose Match all nodes. If you have multiple Jenkins slaves, and don't want all of them to have a selenium node, use match from label expression, and type in master for the Jenkins master. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: ah ok, I had no inkling that this would actually run anything. I had a look after install but thought it was to configure how the grid connects to presumably preexisting nodes. Maybe it could be renamed from 'configurations' to 'nodes'? Also some mention could be made that it's possible to start a node after you've set it up, or even just start a default one after installation.

Comment: Well the thing is that a configuration does not have to match to one node, it's a node configuration, which can create multiple new nodes, therefore I don't think configuration is a bad name per se.

Comment: I had no idea that the 'configurations' was to do with 'nodes', hence this question.

Comment: I'll think about changing the name :)

Comment: Imagining and empathising with the state of ignorance is the hardest skill for anyone designing user interfaces :D

Comment: By the way, if you have any issues or suggestions fit the plugin, feel free to make an issue in the jenkins jira or on github.

Comment: Thanks! I've already just posted another question as haven't got it running yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947888/