# How to pass PhantomJS path to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, jenkins, phantomjs

I'm getting an error when trying to set up a phantomjs node on Selenium Grid (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)

I've set up the following custom json configuration:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "phantomjs",
      "phantomjs.binary.path": "/usr/bin/phantomjs",
      "platform": "LINUX",
      "maxInstances": 5
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "nodeTimeout":120,
    "port":5555,
    "hubPort":4444,
    "hubHost":"localhost",
    "nodePolling":2000,
    "registerCycle":10000,
    "register":true,
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "maxSession":1
  }
}
```

But I get an error when I run webdriver against it:

```
WebDriverException: Message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The latest version can be downloaded from http://phantomjs.org/download.html
Stacktrace:
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState (Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS (PhantomJSDriverService.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService (PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init> (PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor (DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance (DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance (DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "phantomjs"}}
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: Finished Request
```

If I stop the node started by the plugin (and keep the plugin hub running), and manually run my own node as follows, it works fine:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver 
    -browser browserName=phantomjs,platform=LINUX 
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

[edit] phantomjs is executable from the shell and lives at /usr/bin/phantomjs:

```
$ whereis phantomjs
phantomjs: /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

I can't find a canonical description online of a phantomjs setup and this isn't one of the default browser options provided by the plugin.

---

The problem with the above was the OS permissions on `/usr/bin/phantomjs`; I needed to do `chmod a+x` on it.

---

**Cheekily adding this additional problem**

This works (manually started by me):

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver -browser browserName=phantomjs,platform=LINUX -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register`

This doesn't (the process started by the selenium plugin):

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.56.jar hudson.remoting.Launcher -cp /var/lib/jenkins/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/htmlunit-driver-standalone-2.20.jar -connectTo localhost:36322`

Error I'm getting when running the test:
`PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available`

Comment: Be aware that you're setting max instances to 5, but max sessions to 1, so you'll never have more than one test running at the same time, even though 5 are available.

Comment: Also what is the output of whereis phantomjs

Comment: `# which phantomjs
/usr/bin/phantomjs`

Comment: Please check if phantomjs has 'x' (execute) access for all users. If it doesnt, then use the command to change the access.
chmod +x /usr/bin/phantomjs

Comment: What is the command line and uid of the node process started by the plugin?

Comment: In your custom json configuration, try replacing `"capabilities"` with `"desiredCapabilities"`.

Comment: You can also try removing `"phantomjs.binary.path"` from your configuration, since the `phantomjs` executable is obviously on your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Leon I just got "Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities" for the change to `desiredCapabilities`

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur yes this actually was the problem! It only had the execute privilege for the owner/root ... I'll award you the bonus points (do you need to write it up in an actual answer?)
Meanwhile I'm still not getting it actually running so have added an addendum to the question in case anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the answer just in case someone misses the comment.

Please check if phantomjs has 'x' (execute) access for all users. If it doesnt, then use the command to change the access.

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

The new error "The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available" mostly comes with selenium/driver version mismatch. You could try downgrading the version of selenium.

Btw, what version of phantomjs are you using.

Comment: Sorry, the bounty has expired and I can't award it to you :(
I tried: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/how-can-i-award-the-bounty-to-someone-who-only-posted-a-comment/

Comment: @EoghanM No issues :)
Did your other problem got solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Dphantomjs.binary.path=/usr/bin/phantomjs` to your Java flags for Jenkins (typically look to `/etc/default/jenkins` or `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`).

Answer (score 0):

juste add path in command line like this:

```
'/usr/bin/java' -Dphantomjs.binary.path='/home/john/.local/share/binman_phantomjs/linux64/2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs' -jar '/home/john/.local/share/binman_seleniumserver/generic/3.0.1/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar'
```